# Facebook Login issue using web SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have integrated a Facebook OAuth login into my website. I have used the same script specified in the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/), But am getting a blank screen for the popup. While inspecting the browser console, I could see the below error message. I have used the same script specified in the doc and replaced the APPID and Graph API versions. I have used v19.0 as the Graph API version.

> ErrorUtils caught an error:
>
> Minified invariant #21945;
>
> Subsequent non-fatal errors won't be logged; see
> https://fburl.com/debugjs.

I have used the below code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>

  function statusChangeCallback(response) {  // Called with the results from FB.getLoginStatus().
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);                   // The current login status of the person.
    if (response.status === 'connected') {   // Logged into your webpage and Facebook.
      testAPI();  
    } else {                                 // Not logged into your webpage or we are unable to tell.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this webpage.';
    }
  }


  function checkLoginState() {               // Called when a person is finished with the Login Button.
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {   // See the onlogin handler
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }


  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'APPID',
      cookie     : true,                     // Enable cookies to allow the server to access the session.
      xfbml      : true,                     // Parse social plugins on this webpage.
      version    : 'v19.0'           // Use this Graph API version for this call.
    });


    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {   // Called after the JS SDK has been initialized.
      statusChangeCallback(response);        // Returns the login status.
    });
  };
 
  function testAPI() {                      // Testing Graph API after login.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }

</script>


<!-- The JS SDK Login Button -->

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>

<!-- Load the JS SDK asynchronously -->
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```